# How retrieve data in every random key and display in recyclerview. Im using firebase database Please click the link to see the image thanks

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Firebase Database structure

[image]

I want to retrieve every data inside every random key. Specially in the "foods" column with the name `productName` and `qty`.
Thanks

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public RecyclerView recyclerView, recyclerView1;
    public DatabaseReference ref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final DatabaseReference requestsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Requests");
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_food);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        Query firstRequestQuery = requestsRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(1);
        firstRequestQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot requestSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food,FoodViewHolder> adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Food, FoodViewHolder>(
                            Food.class,
                            R.layout.individual_row,
                            FoodViewHolder.class,
                            requestSnapshot.getRef().child("foods")
                    ) {
                        @Override
                        protected void populateViewHolder(FoodViewHolder viewHolder, Food model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setProductName(model.getProductName());
                        viewHolder.setQuantity(model.getQuantity());
                        }
                    };
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

THE FOOD CLASS

public class Food {

```
public String productName , quantity;


public Food(String productName, String quantity) {
    this.productName = productName;
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public Food() {

}

public String getProductName() {
    return productName;
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    this.productName = productName;
}

public String getQuantity() {
    return quantity;
}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    this.quantity = quantity;
}
}
```

THE FoodViewHolder

public class FoodViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView text_productName , text_quantity;

```
public FoodViewHolder(View itemView) {
    super(itemView);
    text_productName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_name);
    text_quantity = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.food_qty);
}

public void setProductName(String productName) {
    text_productName.setText(productName);

}

public void setQuantity(String quantity) {
    text_quantity.setText(quantity);

}
```

}

Comment: Kindly be more specific to what you're asking. What is the random key here?

Comment: Please also add the content of your `Food` class.